# How to check whether there are **saved** associated records rather than **in-memory** associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have two associated models:

```
class HelpRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :donation_items, dependent: :destroy
```

and

```
class DonationItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :help_request
```

I have a validator that returns an error to the user if he/she tries to save a `help_request` with no `donation_items`.

```
validate :has_donation_items?
...
def has_donation_items?
  if !self.donation_items.present?
    errors.add :a_help_request, "must have at least one item."
  end
end
```

This, though, is checking on the current, in-memory state before save. However, I have a need, when re-rendering the form, even if there is an unsaved `donation_item` for the `help_request` to test whether there are any saved `donation_items` for the `help_request`.

Is there a way to test for **saved** associated `donation_items` **without** having to step through each in-memory `donation_item` and test whether it's a new record?

I'm hoping there's something simple like this (obviously made-up) example:

```
@help_request.saved_donation_items.present?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use collect and any?
This does sort of loop through your items but it is fairly concise

`@help_request.donation_items.collect{|di| di.persisted?}.any?`

Or hit the database again (assuming help_request has been saved)

`HelpRequest.find(@help_request.id).donation_items.any?`

Comment: Used the "hit the database" method. Not sure if it's more efficient, but I like that it doesn't have to step through all the records as the collect method does. Any idea which method is "best practice" in terms of minimizing server load?

Comment: In terms of reducing load the collect method would be more efficient.

Comment: The guiding principle would be to reduce the number of database queries whenever possible. When  you retrieve @help_request use `includes`, to fetch donation items in the same query http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes  .